# construct and fill PHP array based on exploded string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I think I am just plain stupid but I can't seem to get this to go. I have a string which I subsequently turn into an array

```
$string = "apple;pears;bananas";
$array = explode(";", $string);
```

The values of $array each need to be in its own array with the following base structure:

```
$basearray = array(
    "label" => "",
    "value" => "",
    );
```

ultimately yielding an array of three arrays , where label and value of the first array are both "apples", "pears" for the second array etc. The trick is that the initial string might be longer/shorter (say "apple;pears;bananas;kiwis;strawberries"; and should thus yield a different amount of arrays.
I hope I make myself clear enough :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a use case for [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$string = 'apple;pears;bananas';
$array = explode(';', $string);

$result = array_map(fn($item) => [ 'label' => $item, 'value' => $item], $array);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => apple
            [value] => apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => pears
            [value] => pears
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => bananas
            [value] => bananas
        )

)
```

Comment: perfect! that worked like a charm